# Angular NVD3: set a yDomain in stackedAreaChart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm using:

- [**Angular**](https://angularjs.org/) `v.1.3`
- [**Angular-nvd3**](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) `v.1.0.5`
- [**D3**](https://d3js.org/) `v.3.5.16`

I tried to add a **Stacket Area Chart** with a **specific domain in Y axis** and I'm glad with the result because the yDomain and the chart is working, but I have a little design issue that I want to solve...

---

#### Without a domain in Y axis:

Is working correctly, without any issue, but is not exactly that I want:

[image: chart without domain]

#### With a domain in Y axis

With the last situation, I added now a domain in Y axis:

```
 var maxValue, minValue, margin;
  
 maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math,data[0].values.map(function(o){return o[1];}));
 minValue = Math.min.apply(Math,data[0].values.map(function(o){return o[1];}));
 margin = 0.1 * (maxValue - minValue);
 options.chart.yDomain = [minValue, maxValue+margin];
```

And now is just exactly that I want! I added a domain... But I don't understand why the **X axis and the chart are underhand**...

[image: chart with domain]

How can I solve this design issue? Why is this happening?

*Thank you!*

---

#### Chart properties:

```
"chart": {
    "type": "stackedAreaChart",
    "height": 450,
    "margin": {
      "top": 20,
      "right": 20,
      "bottom": 20,
      "left": 40
    },
    "x": function (d) {
      return d[0];
    },
    "y": function (d) {
      return d[1];
    },
    "useVoronoi": false,
    "clipEdge": true,
    "showControls": false,
    "duration": 100,
    "useInteractiveGuideline": true,
    "xAxis": {
      "tickFormat": function (d) {
        return d3.time.format("%H:%M")(new Date(d));
      }
    },
    "yAxis": {
      "tickFormat": function (d) {
        return d3.format(",.2f")(d);
      },
    },
    "zoom": {
      "enabled": false,
      "scaleExtent": [1, 10],
      "useFixedDomain": true,
      "useNiceScale": false,
      "horizontalOff": true,
      "verticalOff": true,
      "unzoomEventType": "dblclick.zoom"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue changing the type of chart from **stackedAreaChart** to **lineChart**.

```
"chart": {
    "type": "lineChart",
    // ... All the other options are the same
```

After that, the only change that we need to do is add `area:true` in the **data** object, and we obtain the **same chart with this bug solved**.

```
data = [{
          color:"#e35b5a",
          key:"A",
          values:values,
          area: true //Add this line in the data object
       }];
```

**Result:**

[image: Chart without issues]